# Classes in email getting prefixed by some code

Tags: php, email

I'm sending emails to users in my appplication using PHP. I've added [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/) classes to my email html body. But in email these classes are coming with some prefixed code.

Example:

```
<p class="w3-text-red"></p>
```

is coming inside email like

```
<p class="yse34jkkw3-text-red"></p>
```

I checked in yahoo and gmail emails and in both some code are getting added inside every class.

How can I avoid this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They do this to prevent conflicts with the rest of the page.

Comment: @ceejayoz  Is there any meta tags or other methods I can use to prevent this?

Comment: No, you cannot prevent this. Most people use a HTML email preflight/premail system to inline their CSS rules instead of using an external stylesheet, which prevents this prefixing from causing any issues.